# Is it possible to proxy my custom .local address to a port?

Tags: proxy, node.js

I want my local server (available at `localhost:12345`, where `12345` is a random port) reachable via `custom.local` (which is enabled via `multicast-dns`). I have console logs setup to ensure things are working when visiting both addresses in the browser.

How do I combine the two? Seems like a proxy is the way to go. Is this even possible?

I'm basically trying to do the equivalent of nginx's proxy pass in my Node.js project. This is how it looks in nginx:

```
server {
    server_name custom.local;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:12345;
    }
}
```

Comment: *How do I combine the two?* I am not sure what you mean. Do you mean that you want it be accessable on the web? Like any other web site? Are you running your site at home? Are you intending to run this at home with dynamic DNS? If so, you have options. Look into port forwarding on your router/firewall. That may be your answer. As well, you may need to assign a private IP to the sever and configure the web server to answer on that IP. Apache, for example, is configured for the localhost IP which is 127.0.0.1. You will need to add a routable IP for the port forward.

Comment: @closetnoc No, I just want it available on my own computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND A SOLUTION, WOOP WOOP!

I'm using [this module](https://github.com/bbeldame/local.dev/blob/master/index.js), but tweaked the source a bit (only because I have dynamic ports, because I feel like it).

```
/* jshint undef: true, unused: true, esversion: 6, node: true */



"use strict";



//
//  G E T
//  P A C K A G E S

import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import local from "./server/local";

const n = express();



n.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome home");
});



//
//  L A U N C H

const server = http.createServer(n);

server.listen(0, () => {
  const port = server.address().port;
  local.add(port, "custom.local");
});
```

Hope this helps you as well, future Internet searcher! :D
Don't let negative folks on other SE sites bring you down. :virtual fist bump: